# Sort array into assoc array but add consecutive dates on same rate

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of rates.

```
$rates = array(
    0  => 200,
    1  => 150,
    2  => 150,
    3  => 220,
    4  => 300,
    5  => 310,
    6  => 350,
    7  => 325,
    8  => 325,
    9 => 325,
    10 => 300,
);
```

So it must be formatted by taking todays date as the first date and adding into the assoc array the following start_date, finish_date, rate, if there are two or more consecutive dates then that gets pushed in the same index but the finsih date will end depending how many days the rate was the same here is an example of how it should look.

```
$new_rates = array (
    'start_date' => '2018-12-07'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-07'
    'rate' => '200',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-08'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-09'
    'rate' => '150',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-10'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-10'
    'rate' => '220',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-11'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-11'
    'rate' => '300',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-12'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-12'
    'rate' => '310',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-13'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-13'
    'rate' => '350',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-14'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-15'
    'rate' => '325',
    'start_date' => '2018-12-16'
    'finish_date' => '2018-12-16'
    'rate' => '300',
);
```

As you can see the first start_date can start on todays date etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: create result array manually and put here result of var_export($new rates)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry Im not being clear here, I want to loop through that initial array to create the effect of the associative array

Answer (score 0):

Your expected array has a problem.

```
'start_date' => '2018-12-07'
'finsih_date' => '2018-12-07'
'rate' => '200',

'start_date' => '2018-12-08'
'finsih_date' => '2018-12-09'
'rate' => '150',
```

You are repeating the key start_date, finish_date, rate. So if you try to assign new start date then it will overwrite the previous start date. (assoc_array is a hash table in PHP)

I suggest you to follow this structure instead,

```
$new_rates = [

   [
     'start_date' => '2018-12-07'
     'finsih_date' => '2018-12-07'
     'rate' => '200',
   ],

    [
    'start_date' => '2018-12-08'
    'finsih_date' => '2018-12-09'
    'rate' => '150',
   ]

]
```

Or

```
$new_rates = [

   200 => [
     'start_date' => '2018-12-07'
     'finsih_date' => '2018-12-07'
   ],

    150 =>[
    'start_date' => '2018-12-08'
    'finsih_date' => '2018-12-09'
   ]

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think I see what you're tryig to accomplish, hope this helps - you might probably want to work on cleaning/leaning the code up a bit for your specific use case, but it gets the job done.

```
<?php
$rates = array(200, 150, 150, 220, 300, 310, 350, 325, 325, 325, 300);

$count = count($rates);
$previousRate = null; // check for duplicate rates
$uniqueRates = []; // store for unique rates
$duplicateRates = []; // store for duplicate rates
$duplicateCount = 0;
/* fill the stores with uniqueRates and duplicateRates */
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $currentRate = $rates[$i]; // take rate
    if($currentRate !== $previousRate) { // not a duplicate rate
        $duplicateCount = 0;
        $uniqueRates[]=$currentRate;
        $previousRate = $rates[$i]; // duplicate check store
    } else { // duplicate rate
        $duplicateCount++;
        $duplicateRates[$currentRate] = $duplicateCount; // store duplicate rate
        continue;
    }
}

$counter = 0;
foreach($uniqueRates as $key => $rate) {
    $dateUnique = date("Y-m-d",
        mktime(null, null, null,
            date("m"), date("d") + $counter, date("Y")));
    if(!key_exists($rate, $duplicateRates)) { // not a duplicate rate
        $newArr[$counter]['start_date'] = $dateUnique;
        $newArr[$counter]['end_date'] = $dateUnique;
        $newArr[$counter]['rate'] = $rate;
    } else { // duplicate rate
        $dateDuplicate = date("Y-m-d",
            mktime(null, null, null,
                date("m"), date("d") + $counter + 1, date("Y")));
        $newArr[$counter]['start_date'] = $dateUnique;
        $newArr[$counter]['end_date'] = $dateDuplicate; // adjusted date for duplicate rates
        $newArr[$counter]['rate'] = $rate;
        $counter++;
    }
    $counter++;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-08' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-08' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 200
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-09' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-10' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 150
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-11' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-11' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 220
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-12' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-12' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 300
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-13' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-13' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 310
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-14' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-14' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 350
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-15' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-16' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 325
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_date' => string '2018-12-17' (length=10)
      'end_date' => string '2018-12-17' (length=10)
      'rate' => int 300
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but its only half way there, you see for example array index 1 and 2 are both 150, so what should happen in the logic is the rate 150 should just be in one array index but the finish date should be 2018-12-09, can you see what I am trying to do, so any consecutive rates should be in one array index but the finish date will be however many days the same rate went on for, I hope this makes sense.